# How to iterate each character from a string and add a vbcrlf in certain character VB.net

Tags: string, vb.net, foreach, newline, literate-programming

So, i have a text file. The purpose is to Add VBLF (newline) in certain part of string using VB.net. Here the example of the string:

Before (The string don't have any newline caharcter):

`{1:F01ABCDIDJAXXXX0001212544}{2:O9001038231020QWERIDJRAXXX00011102422310201038N}{3:{113:0070}}{4::20:94493831555385/900:21:0799102034308001:25:520008000990:32A:231020USD0,:72:/ESETDATE/2310201038+0000/OID/231020ABCDDJAXXXX0001019040/AMNT/10000000000001,12-}`

After:

if we see on notepad ++ will look like this [open image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E64ID.png)

I was think that we need to iterate through each character.
Below is my logic:

1.Find character

> {4:

in whole string, then replace with  **{4: + vbLf**

2. Replace regex

For each character with pattern

> ^:[\d\w]+:

(like :20: )
Then replace with **vbLf + originalcharacter**

3. Replace regex

For each character with pattern

> /(.*?)/

(like \AMNT\ )

Then replace with **vbLf + originalcharacter**

If anyone can help to solve this, appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Break down your problem and deal with it like that. Do you know how to add a LF character? Write that code. Do you know when you want to split the line? Write that code. You'll need to show the code you've tried for us to help you.

Comment: Even if you're not experienced at writing code, you're still as capable as anyone of applying logic, so you should be able to describe the specific logical steps required to go from your actual input to your desired output. Until you know what the code has to do, you can't possibly know that you can't write it, so it's far too soon for you to be asking us for help. As for all programming problems, break it down into elementary steps, formalise those steps into an algorithm and then do your best to implement as many steps as possible for yourself. Ask us about one specific step you can't do.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, i am confuse to write the syntax but still trying to write any code.

Comment: here my logic: 

1.Find character “{4:” in whole string, then replace with “{4:”+vbLf  

 2. Replace regex

For each character with pattern
 ^:[\d\w]+:
(like :20: )
Then replace with vbLf+originalcharacter

3. Replace regex

For each character with pattern
\\\w\\
(like \AMNT\ )
Then replace with vbLf+originalcharacter

Comment: No one should need to read the comments to understand the question. Edit your question and provide ALL the relevant information. That includes the detailed logic that you're trying to implement and your best attempt to implement it.

Comment: i've revised my question, thanks for the input

Comment: You can use the [String.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.8.1) method to find the index of "{4:". While you're on that documentation site, have a look at other things like Substring and Insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution **without using regex**:

```
Sub test()

    Dim YourString As String = "{1:F01ABCDIDJAXXXX0001212544}{2:O9001038231020QWERIDJRAXXX00011102422310201038N}{3:{113:0070}}{4::20:94493831555385/900:21:0799102034308001:25:520008000990:32A:231020USD0,:72:/ESETDATE/2310201038+0000/OID/231020ABCDDJAXXXX0001019040/AMNT/10000000000001,12-}"
    Debug.Print(DoIt(YourString))

End Sub

Function DoIt(sLine As String) As String

    Dim aTemp1() As String
    Dim aTemp2() As String
    Dim aTemp3() As String

    Dim sResult As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Try

        aTemp1 = sLine.Split("{4:")
        aTemp2 = aTemp1(1).Split(":", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        aTemp3 = aTemp2.Last.Split("/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        '"{1:F01ABCDIDJAXXXX0001212544}{2:O9001038231020QWERIDJRAXXX00011102422310201038N}{3:{113:0070}}{4:" & vbLf
        sResult = aTemp1(0) & "{4:" & vbLf

        '":20:94493831555385/900" & vbLf & ":21:0799102034308001" & vbLf & ":25:520008000990" & vbLf & ":32A:231020USD0," & vbLf
        For i = 0 To aTemp2.Length - 3 Step 2
            sResult &= ":" & aTemp2(i) & ":"
            sResult &= aTemp2(i + 1) & vbLf
        Next

        '":72:"
        sResult &= ":" & aTemp2(i) & ":"

        '/ESETDATE/2310201038+0000" & vbLf & "/OID/231020ABCDDJAXXXX0001019040" & vbLf & "/AMNT/10000000000001,12-}" & vbLf
        For i = 0 To aTemp3.Length - 1 Step 2
            sResult &= "/" & aTemp3(i) & "/" & aTemp3(i + 1) & vbLf
        Next

        'vbLf & "-}"
        sResult = sResult.Replace("-", vbLf & "-") ' <-- You forgot this part

        Return sResult

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return String.Empty
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help @nick abbot, this can be my additional reference.I have tried using regex and lucky it works.